# Splitting data based on semi colon and picking up unique IDs

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have file that looks like this:

```
26. ZINC19693599
27. ZINC19693598
28. AKOS032468089; ZINC575619353; F6561-5795 ...
29. MolPort-039-321-788; ZINC46759513; AKOS030658283
30. MolPort-039-315-229; AKOS030665655; ZINC108730091
31. MolPort-039-285-275; ZINC253426468; Z1983921961 ...
32. MolPort-039-260-085; ZINC293540464; Z2220694059 ...
33. MolPort-039-256-805; ZINC240871409; Z1978986809 ...
36. MolPort-042-618-243; AKOS026704656; ZINC575617472 ...
37. MolPort-042-617-677; AKOS026704258; ZINC575615033 ...
39. CHEMBL3446533; AKOS030350184; ZINC257247314
40. ZINC257240872
41. AKOS030286562; ZINC257302698
42. AKOS030286561; ZINC257339418
43. AKOS030262257; ZINC257197602
44. MolPort-038-977-160; ZINC225411464; Z1945656395 ...
45. MolPort-038-969-994; AKOS030642012; ZINC191511001
46. MolPort-035-834-516; ZINC170605844; Z366648930 ...
47. MolPort-035-834-509; ZINC170605825; Z366645258 ...
48. ZINC170591573
49. ZINC170591572
50. MolPort-038-956-852; ZINC135661620; Z1443333613 ...
51. MolPort-038-958-774; ZINC119501018; Z1542315705 ...
52. AKOS030442141; ZINC100744266; ZINC257344663
53. AKOS030406331; ZINC100216414; ZINC257287859
54. AKOS030389515; ZINC100159328; ZINC257263109 ...
55. AKOS030389402; ZINC100158990; ZINC257223925
56. AKOS030389401; ZINC100158986; ZINC257331241
57. ZINC97137184
58. ZINC97137179
59. ZINC96485930
```

Each line should have `ZINC` ID (it surely starts with `ZINC`, but length of ID might not be the same). I am trying to `grep` from each line this ID that starts with `ZINC`.

In my result I would expect to have something that looks like this:

```
ZINC19693599
ZINC19693598
ZINC575619353
ZINC46759513
ZINC108730091
ZINC253426468
ZINC240871409
..etc
```

Can anybody help how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first `grep` then `sort -u` to remove the duplicates, so based on your file format, you can do

```
grep -o 'ZINC[^;]*' infile |sort -u
```

The `ZINC[^;]*` is matching the patterns having `ZINC` followed by anything until `;` seen and excluded `;` itself.

Comment: This should work provided no other fields are allowed to contain the word "ZINC"...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with `sed`.  Something like this might do:

```
sed -En 's/^(.*; )?(ZINC[^;]+).*$/\2/p' < input.txt
```

A brief rundown of what it is doing:

1. tell sed to use extended regular expressions, and not print lines by default.
2. the `s/.../.../p` syntax tells sed to perform a regexp **s**earch and replace, then **p**rint matching lines.
3. The first part of the regexp `^(.*; )?` says to start at the beginning of the line either match any characters up to a `"; "` (i.e. some number of semi-colon delimited items), or nothing at all (i.e. if the ID is the first item).
4. `(ZINC[^;]+)` matches your ZINC... ID, accepting any non-semi-colon character as part of the ID.
5. `.*$` matches the remainder of the line.
6. The replacement for the match is `\2`, which is the second parenthesised group in the regular expression (i.e. the ZINC... ID).  Since the regexp matches the entire line, we're left with just the ID.

If the format is as you've described, this is probably enough.  If it is more complex (e.g. with special quoting rules), you should probably look for a tool that understands the format.